Robust Computation of Inverse Stieltjes Transform
I'm interested in finding a small set of procedures which I can use to compute inverse Stieltjes Transform for a random variable. I'm interested in

Stieltjes transform

solved: Expectation[1/(s - x), x \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[1/2, 1]]


Symbolic inverse Stieltjes transform
Symbolic inverse Stieltjes transform for $s\to 0$
Numeric inverse Stieltjes transform I would use as spot-check against ground-truth by plotting

Below are continuous r.v.s I'm interested in. What's special about them is that Mathematica discovers a simple closed form expression for their for CDF at $x\to 0$ regime, suggesting that symbolic Stieltjes transform at $s\to 0$ should also be feasible.
pairs = {
   {"Uniform", UniformDistribution[]},
   {"Beta", BetaDistribution[1/2, 1]},
   {"Triangle", TriangularDistribution[]},
   {"Kumaraswamy(2,3)", KumaraswamyDistribution[2, 3]},
   {"ArcSin", ArcSinDistribution[]},
   {"Pareto(1,2)", ParetoDistribution[1, 2]},
   {"InverseGamma", InverseGammaDistribution[1, 2]},
   {"Frechet(2,1,0)", FrechetDistribution[2, 1, 0]},
   {"Semi-circle", WignerSemicircleDistribution[2]},
   {"Marchenko-Pastur", MarchenkoPasturDistribution[1]},
   {"Weibull", WeibullDistribution[1/2, 4]},
   {"Extreme Value", ExtremeValueDistribution[]},
   {"Rayleigh(1)", RayleighDistribution[1]},
   {"Erlang(1,2)", ErlangDistribution[2, 1]},
   {"Gamma(1,2)", GammaDistribution[1, 2]},
   {"Bates(3)", BatesDistribution[3]},
   {"Gumbel", GumbelDistribution[]},
   {"Chi", ChiDistribution[1]},
   {"ChiSquared", ChiSquareDistribution[1]},
   {"MaxwellDistribution(1/2)", MaxwellDistribution[1/2]},
   {"Student-T", StudentTDistribution[1]},
   {"Exponential", ExponentialDistribution[1/2]},
   {"Normal", NormalDistribution[]},
   {"Pareto(1,2)", ParetoDistribution[1, 2]},
   {"Cauchy", CauchyDistribution[]},
   {"Logistic", LogisticDistribution[]},
   {"Hotelling(1,30)", HotellingTSquareDistribution[1, 30]},
   {"F-ratio", FRatioDistribution[1, 1]},
   {"Gamma[1,4,1/2,0]", GammaDistribution[1, 4, 1/2, 0]},
   {"BetaPrime", BetaPrimeDistribution[1/2, 1/2, 1, 1]},
   {"Laplace", LaplaceDistribution[]},
   {"Sech", SechDistribution[]},
   {"Exponential Power", ExponentialPowerDistribution[1]},
   {"ShiftedGompertzDistribution", 
    ShiftedGompertzDistribution[1, 1/2]},
   {"Moyal", MoyalDistribution[]},
   {"Levy", LevyDistribution[0, 1]},
   {"Rice", RiceDistribution[0, 2]},
   {"Hoyt", HoytDistribution[1, 2]},
   {"K-distribution", KDistribution[2, 2]},
   {"Nakagami", NakagamiDistribution[1, 3]},
   {"Log-Gamma", LogGammaDistribution[2, 1, 1]},
   {"Exp-Gamma", ExpGammaDistribution[1, 2, 1]}
   };

Here's a discrete r.v. I'm interested in computing forward/inverse Stieltjes transform for:
y = TransformedDistribution[1/z^2, z \[Distributed] ZipfDistribution[1]];
stieltjes = Expectation[1/(s - i), i \[Distributed] distY]; (* (3 (Sqrt[s] - \[Pi] Cot[\[Pi]/Sqrt[s]]))/(\[Pi]^2 Sqrt[s]) *)
inverseStieltjes = 42 

<TODO(y): add other Discrete Distributions in Mathematica>
I would wrap this up small set of functions like was done with to ilaplaceMellin, ilaplaceFeynmann in laplace-transform-tricks.nb for Inverse Laplace Transform and post on Mathematica Community.
Notebook
Related posts:

Oct 9, 2024, Inverse Stieltjes Transform Implementation?
Jun 25, 2023 Visualizing density given by its Stieltjes transformation?


Mathematica fail to compute: disto = Transpose[pairs][[2]]; Expectation[1/(s - x),   x \[Distributed] disto[[n]]] where: n=34,35,42 ?
I haven't checked  for all n of them ?

@MariuszIwaniuk I filtered these distributions based on ability of Mathematica to get closed for expression for CDF at 0 (see details), so some of them might not be able to get Stieltjes formula

I have only answer for first question: "Symbolic inverse Stieltjes transform"
Using:
HoldForm[InverseStieltjestransform[
Expectation[1/(s - i), i \[Distributed] dist], s, x] == 
InverseLaplaceTransform[
InverseLaplaceTransform[
Expectation[1/(s - i), i \[Distributed] dist], s, -t], t, x] == 
Expectation[
InverseLaplaceTransform[InverseLaplaceTransform[1/(s - i), s, -t],
t, x], i \[Distributed] dist] == 
Expectation[DiracDelta[-i + x], 
i \[Distributed] dist]==Integrate[
DiracDelta[-i + x]*PDF[Distribution, x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] ==
InverseLaplaceTransform[
MomentGeneratingFunction[Distribution, t] /. t -> -t, t, x]] // TraditionalForm

for example:
distYY = TransformedDistribution[1/z^2, z \[Distributed] 
ZipfDistribution[1]];
stieltjes = Expectation[1/(s - i), i \[Distributed] 
distYY]
(*(3 (Sqrt[s]-\[Pi] Cot[\[Pi]/Sqrt[s]]))/(\[Pi]^2 Sqrt[s])*)

Simplify[Expectation[DiracDelta[-i + x], i \[Distributed] distYY], 
Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]

(*Inverse Stieltjes transform for: (3 (Sqrt[s]-\[Pi] Cot[\
\[Pi]/Sqrt[s]]))/(\[Pi]^2 Sqrt[s]) is:(6 DiracDelta[-1+x])/ (\[Pi]^2)*)

and for Distribution :
pairs = {{"Kumaraswamy", KumaraswamyDistribution[2, 3]}, {"Weihbul", 
WeibullDistribution[1/2, 2]}, {"ArcSin", 
ArcSinDistribution[]}, {"Bates", 
BatesDistribution[3]}, {"Uniform", 
UniformDistribution[]}, {"Pareto", 
ParetoDistribution[1, 2]}, {"Frechet", 
FrechetDistribution[2, 1, 0]}, {"Erlang", 
ErlangDistribution[3, 2]}, {"Gamma", 
GammaDistribution[2, 3]}, {"InverseGamma", 
InverseGammaDistribution[2, 3]}, {"Beta", 
BetaDistribution[1/2, 1]}, {"Marchenko-Pastur", 
MarchenkoPasturDistribution[1]}, {"Semicircle", 
WignerSemicircleDistribution[1]}, {"Cauchy", 
CauchyDistribution[]}, {"Pareto", 
ParetoDistribution[1, 2]}, {"Normal", 
NormalDistribution[]}, {"Student-T", 
StudentTDistribution[1]}, {"ChiSquared", 
ChiSquareDistribution[1]}, {"Chi", 
ChiDistribution[1]}, {"Exponential", ExponentialDistribution[1]}}; 

name = Transpose[pairs][[1]]; 
disto = Transpose[pairs][[2]];
A = Join[{{"Lp", "Name", " Stieltjes transform", 
"Inverse Stieltjes transform"}}, 
Table[{n, name[[n]], 
Expectation[1/(s - x), x \[Distributed] disto[[n]]] // Simplify, 
Simplify[
Expectation[DiracDelta[-i + x], i \[Distributed] disto[[n]]], 
Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]}, {n, 1, 20}]];
Grid[A, Frame -> All]


What I wrote above makes only sense as soon as we know a Distribution.
